# Under what conditions is this tensor isotropic?

Tags: tensor-calculus

The tensor I'm talking about is

\begin{equation}\tag{1} A_{ij}=\int d{\Omega}\,T_{ij}(\theta,\varphi) \end{equation}

where the integral is over the whole solid angle. I know that an isotropic tensor is proportional to $\delta_{ij}$, but I'd like to know under what conditions on $T_{ij}(\theta,\varphi)$ is $A_{ij}$ isometric without doing the integral explicitly.

Extension:

If a tensor in the form of (1) is always isotropic as it is an angular average of another one, what happens, for example, with the quadrupole moment? I mean, it could be written in the (1) form:

$$Q_{ij}=\int d^3\vec{x}\,\rho(\vec{x})\Big[x_ix_j-\vec{x}^2\delta_{ij}\Big]=\int d\Omega\int r^2 dr\,\rho(r,\theta,\varphi)\Big[x_i(r,\theta,\varphi)x_j(r,\theta,\varphi)-r^2\delta_{ij}\Big]=\\=\int d\Omega\,T_{ij}(\theta,\varphi)$$

with

$$T_{ij}(\theta,\varphi)=\int r^2dr\,\rho(r,\theta,\varphi)\Big[x_i(r,\theta,\varphi)x_j(r,\theta,\varphi)-r^2\delta_{ij}\Big],$$

and if this was true, $Q_{ij}$ would be proportional to $\delta_{ij}$. Besides, as $Q_{ij}$ is traceless by definition, it would be 0. Where am I wrong?

Comment: A tensor is, in coordinates, a matrix of coefficients $T_{ij}$. You are instead dealing with a more complicated object: there is a further dependence on angles whose meaning is obscure. I suspect that you are dealing with a tensor valued function that is equivariant with respect to $SO(3)$…

Answer (score 0):

I would say that, as you are averaging over all angles, the tensor is *always* isotropic.

Answer (score 0):

With no further information on any of the quantities, you already answered your own question. It must hold that

$$\int T_{ij} \, d\Omega \sim \delta_{ij}$$